# No BaseStepListener has been registered - debugging serenity-rest-assured

Tags: java, bdd, rest-assured, cucumber-serenity

Can anybody help me with setting up serenity-rest-assured so that I can debug it from my IDE (IntelliJ)? I just can not believe it is so widespread and it can't be run other than using "gradlew test" command, and thus no debugging of test cases is possible in java.

Googling doesn't help me in any way. Any tips/tutorials/links appreciated.

Comment: What problem exactly do you have? Can you share your project somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

1. To run your features directly in IntelliJ, you need to make sure the main class is set to `net.serenitybdd.cucumber.cli.Main`.
2. I don't really understand why, but my Step classes all need to declare a `@Before` method that runs before any other `@Before` methods that makes a call to `OnStage.setTheStage()` as follows:

```
@Before(order=1)
public void setTheStage() {
  OnStage.setTheStage(new OnlineCast());
}

@Before(order=2)
public void yourOtherBeforeMethod() {
   // your before code goes here
}
```

Comment: It worked for me without adding @Before annotations

Answer (score 0):

check if you missing class annotation

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
```

Answer (score -1):

Authentication missing in your request.

```
given().auth().xxxxxx
```